# CapsuleCRM API ColdFusion Wrapper

Tags: api, coldfusion, wrapper

Looking for a ColdFusion version of the following PHP API wrapper for CapsuleCRM:

```
<?php
// The data you want to send to Capsule CRM in xml format 
// SEE http://capsulecrm.com/help/page/javelin_api_party
```

I'm understanding that this variable contains the XML string...

```
$myxml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n
<person>\n
<title>Mr</title>\n
<firstName>Test12</firstName>\n
<lastName>Tester12</lastName>\n
<jobTitle>Chairman</jobTitle>\n
<organisationName>Big Company</organisationName>\n
<about>Testing</about>\n
</person>";

// The URL to connect with (note the /api/ that's needed and note it's person rather than party) 
// SEE: http://capsulecrm.com/help/page/api_gettingstarted/
$capsulepage =  'https://sample.capsulecrm.com/api/person';
```

However, I don't know how to initiate cURL in ColdFusion.

```
// Initialise the session and return a cURL handle to pass to other cURL functions.
$ch = curl_init($capsulepage);
```

What does the 'curl_setopt_array' function do exactly? Is there a CF equivalent?

```
// set appropriate options NB these are the minimum necessary to achieve a post with a useful response
// ...can and should add more in a real application such as 
// timeout CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT 
// and useragent CURLOPT_USERAGENT
// replace 1234567890123456789 with your own API token from your user preferences page
$options = array(CURLOPT_USERPWD => '1234567890123456789:x',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: text/xml'),
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $myxml
            );
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 

// Do the POST and collect the response for future printing etc then close the session
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$responseInfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but that looks like a basic http post. The equivalent in CF is `cfhttp`. To pass parameters/headers ie `curl_setopt_array` see `cfhttpparam` . http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but that looks like a basic http post. The equivalent in CF is [`cfhttp`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html). To pass parameters/headers (ie `curl_setopt_array`) use [`cfhttpparam`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d85.html).